# failed to load resource and status text is error in ajax jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to load state when user select the country but I am getting the below error

I am using entity framework - database first approach

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()
statusText: "error"

HomeController.cs

```
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.country = new SelectList(_testMvEntities.countries.Select(x =>
                    new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Value = x.countryid.ToString(),
                        Text = x.countryname
                    }),
                "Value",
                "Text");

           return View();
        }

        //select a state based on country
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult GetStateBaseOnCountry(int countryId)
        {
            var lstState = _testMvEntities.states.Where(x => x.countryid == countryId).ToList();
            return Json(lstState);
        }
```

Create.cshtml

```
@model WebTest.Models.student
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

@*<h2>Create</h2>*@

<div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <div>
            StudentName:
            <input type="text" id="name" />
        </div>
        <div>
            CountryName:
            @*1 st intellisense*@
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.country.countryid, (SelectList)ViewBag.country)
        </div>
        <div>
            StateName:
            @*@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.state.stateid, (SelectList)ViewBag.state)*@
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.state.stateid, new List<SelectListItem>(), "--Select--")


        </div>
        <div>
            CityName:
            @*@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.city.cityid, (SelectList)ViewBag.city)*@
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.city.cityid, new List<SelectListItem>(), "--Select--")

        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </div>
    }
</div>

@section scripts{

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#country_countryid').change(function () {
                debugger

                $.ajax({

                    type: 'post',
                    url: '/Home/GetStateBaseOnCountry',
                    data: { countryId : $('#country_countryid').val() },
                    datatype: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        debugger
                        //console.log('data shown :' + data);

                        //$.each(data, function (index, value) {
                        //    debugger
                        //    $('#state.stateid').append('<option value="' + value.StateId + '">' + value.StateName + '</option>');
                        //})

                        var states = "<option value='0'>Select State</option>";
                        for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                            states += "<option value=" + data[x].Value + ">" + data[x].Text + "</option>";
                        }
                        $("#state.stateid").html(states).show();

                    },
                    error: function (_, err) {
                        console.log(_, err)
                    },
                })

            })

        })

    </script>

}
```

student.cs

```
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace WebTest.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    
    public partial class student
    {
        public int studid { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> countryid { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> stateid { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> cityid { get; set; }
    
        public virtual city city { get; set; }
        public virtual country country { get; set; }
        public virtual state state { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**console log**:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfyGZ.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GP9nW.jpg

I don't know which place need correction
need help

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): Add a [mcve] + _"**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text."_

Comment: The `error` callback has three parameters so use all of them. And you have to respect the naming convention defined by jQuery. It's `dataType` and not `datatype`

Comment: @Andreas error is same ```A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.state``` can you help more

Comment: Try to understand what the error tells you. What's a _"circular reference"_? Why could this be bad? And why is this error not part of your question (as text!)?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).